# Exporting TableView Data in Xcode/Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am having users input a list of "serials" into a TableView called "Equipment". Here is the code for the tasks array.

```
var taskMgr: TaskManager = TaskManager()

struct task {
    var serial = "Un-Named"
    //var desc   = "Un-Named"
}
class TaskManager: NSObject {

    //Sets up array of Tasks
    var tasks = [task]()

    //Add Task Function
    func addTask(serial: String){
        tasks.append(task(serial: serial))
        }
}
```

I want to take the table data and export it to a .txt file or .csv with each task on separate lines. What is the best way to do this? Please help I've been stuck for a few days. I'm not sure which way I should approach this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.writeToFile` should be able to do this for you if you map your task array into a string array and then join it into one string with new line as separators

```
let tasksString = tasks.map({ (task) -> String in
    return task.serial
}).joinWithSeparator("\n")

do {
    try tasksString.writeToFile(pathToFile, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} catch {

}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Worked great! Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Now how can i reference that tasksString in another class?

Comment: I am trying to print(tasksString) in another swift file. How can I reference to this?

Comment: Depends on where you are going to access it. 
1. Next view controller -> Then you can pass it along in prepareForSegue. 2. Previous view controller -> you can use a delegate to pass the data.
3. Anywhere -> use a global data store for the task array.